# PHP - sort a multidimensional array by timestamp

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have been tried couple of times before asking here, i've also seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949179/array-sorting-php-by-timestamp)

which is similar to mine but unfortunatly it doesnt work (or i can get it working as well).

I have an array like this:

```
    Array (

  [user_1] => Array 
            (
              [0] => Array
                (
                  [category] => string_var
                  [time] => unix_timestamp 
                ),
              [1] => Array
                (
                  [category] => string_var
                  [time] => unix_timestamp 
                ),
              [2] => Array
                (
                  [category] => string_var
                  [time] => unix_timestamp 
                )
            ),

  [user_2] => Array 
            (
              [0] => Array
                (
                  [category] => string_var
                  [time] => unix_timestamp 
                ),
              [1] => Array
                (
                  [category] => string_var
                  [time] => unix_timestamp 
                ),
              [2] => Array
                (
                  [category] => string_var
                  [time] => unix_timestamp 
                )
            )
      )
```

And for each user i have to sort the 2nd-level array by timestamp.

Hence, i've tried:

```
foreach ($array as $user => $user_data) {

    timestamps = array();

    foreach($user_data as $key => $actual_data) {
       $timestamps[$key] = $actual_data['time'];
    }
    array_multisort($timestamps, SORT_ASC, $user_data);
}

unset($timestamps);
print_r($array); // the original array should now be sorted by timestamp
```

Well, no sorting happens, the final array is exactly = the original one.

**NOTES** :

- the key ['time'] into the 2nd-level array comes from a MYSQL column
  and it's stored as BIGINT. var_dump gives me: `int(1432587949)`, so it shouldnt be a variable type issue
- i have also tried usort, with the same result: no sorting.

Where am i wrong? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
array_walk($array, function(&$arr) {usort($arr, function($a,$b){return ($a["time"] < $b["time"]) ? -1 : ($a["time"] > $b["time"] ? 1 : 0);});});
```

But since you said that the data come from a database then I suggest you sort them there because it's likely to be faster than sorting it in php.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you please rename $data and $arr with the array names of my example? thanks

Comment: @sciakysystem: done, `$arr` is just internal paramater name.

Comment: that worked. Thanks. I was trying with a wrong approach. And you understood this. thanks